# How to derive some part of the Proca lagrangian for a Vector (spin-1)?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, variational-calculus

I'm trying to derive Eq. (10.17) & Eq. (10.18) from the textbook. Where does the term
-1/(4*pi) come from, and how do I cancel out the rest of the term (see my text, second picture).

[image]

[image]

Comment: It would really be helpful if you could type your second image calculation in mathjax. [How?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/) Also, $-\frac{1}{4\pi}$ comes because of factor $4$ when the first term is simplified in Euler-Lagrange equation.